# Gradle Sync: Download https;//jcenter.bintray.com/... running indefinitely

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently moved from windows to ubuntu. And was installing android studio on it. During the installation I faced and error unable to download a failed to load module canberra-gtk-module error which I corrected (did I?) by typing  following in the terminal

```
sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module
```

now once The installaition is complete the android studio had stuck on one process
It shows 1 process running... Gradle Sync: Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/...

Any way to make that piece of software work, did I made a mistake by removing windows completely from my laptop and by moving to linux?

edit:
After some time that syncing stopped and it showed:

> Gradle sync failed: Connection reset (13 m 11 s 843 ms)

and the green play button is also not working

Comment: Just network problems. Check your network.

Comment: I checked my network speed, it is 18Mbps.

Comment: You should check your network to https://jcenter.bintray.com, not only with some speedtest tool.

Comment: I downloaded the Gradle that manually, and changed the settings. And then things worked out correctly

Comment: change wifi / network provider and check.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I was facing is that the android studio was not able to download Gradle. Such problems always occur when ando0rid studio is updated. What I suggest is that go search gradle download on google. open the very first link. And download the latest version.
Then unzip the folder you got. Cut paste into the gradle folder of your android folder. First find out the place you installed android studio. The in it search for Gradle named folder. Paste it there. Remove the gradle folder with older version.

Now start android studio -> File->settings->Build,Execution,development->gradle
The under project-level settings click use local gradle distribution, and put the location of the gradle folder you have pasted previously into Gradle home field. Go change your gradle version and restart your android studio.

I am adding a video link https://youtu.be/btPk12JuZ2U